# Drupal: Proper way to drop a table for module update

Tags: drupal

What is the proper way to drop a table using hook_update_N? I can't find docs on this. If I run update_sql($sql); in my hook--the sql being a drop statement--it reports a failure, even though checking the db, I can see that the table was dropped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use [`db_drop_table()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_drop_table/7) (or the Drupal 6 [version here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.pgsql.inc/function/db_drop_table/6)).

Comment: Odd. I am seeing that if I have two updates, say: mymodule_update_6130 and mymodule_6140 and you run the first (6130), it seems to also run the second (6140). That's why I was getting the db error, because the table was already removed by the first update. Can this be?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in [hook_update_N](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7)

```
/**
 * Drop 'my_table' table.
 */
function MYMODULE_update_7001() {
  if (db_table_exists('my_table')) {
    db_drop_table('my_table');
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo there. It should probably be if(db_table_exists...) without the negation operator :)